# How to specify what block I want to use in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have this Code in Terraform. And I have the outputs.tf. I have assigned variables like os_family in my terraform.tfvars but whenever I do apply it's just dropping cause of `Query returned no results` I think that's because it's trying to query both things. How Can I specify to use the Ubuntu part instead of the RHEL part if I want to install Ubuntu and vice versa for the RHEL? Cause my way is definitely not working. Thank you.

**Main.tf**

```
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-*-${var.os_version}*amd64*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["REDACTED"]
}

data "aws_ami" "rhel" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["RHEL-${var.os_version}*GA*x86_64*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["REDACTED"]
}
```

**outputs.tf**

```
output "image_id" {
  value = var.os_family == "rhel" ? data.aws_ami.rhel.id : data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
}
```

Comment: You need to make both data sources conditional as well by using `count = var.os_family = "rhel" ? 1 : 0` for the `rhel` data source and an equivalent one for the `ubuntu` one.

Comment: I will try and give you a reply. Thank you

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'm not sure where to put it, can you please clarify a bit?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/41870148/2291321 answer your question?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yes it does. Thanks

Comment: Cool. I've closed this as a duplicate then which will help others who come across this question to find that answer.